# net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND: Working on PhpStorm server but not working in the browser

Tags: javascript, html, phpstorm

I am testing an html webpage and in the browser it's not working .It is failing to load:

```
src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"
```

this is the error:

> GET file://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

and I'd like to question another error in the same html webpage that is the following:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at files.html:337

this is the script:

```
$('.toggle').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var $this = $(this);
if ($this.next().hasClass('show')) {
    $this.next().removeClass('show');
    $this.next().slideUp(350);
} else {
    $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').removeClass('show');
    $this.parent().parent().find('li .inner').slideUp(350);
    $this.next().toggleClass('show');
    $this.next().slideToggle(350);
}
});
```

Comment: How did you opened that page? What URL? Notice the `file://` in error -- looks like you have opened it via `file://` .. so I think the error is expected and you would need to use FULL url (`https://cdn...`) if you want to open it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of
`src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"`
Use
`src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"`